# Comparing two fields in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new in MongoDB and trying to compare 2 fields in a collection in MongoDB.

The fields are attributes(object) and collections(array)

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ae1e47309ffcbd1b67bd6c"), 
    "collections" : [
        {
            "collection_code" : "9TEST", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c76eee4bb4afe3a3603eeb3")
        }
    ], 
   "attributes" : {
        "collection_code" : "9TEST"
    }
}
```

My query is

```
db.companies.find({ $where : "this.attributes.collection_code == this.collections[collection_code]" })
```

Getting below error

```
{
    "message" : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection_code' of undefined" +
              "at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:45) near 'on_code == this.collections[collection_co' ",
    "$err" : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection_code' of undefined" +
              "at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:45) near 'on_code == this.collections[collection_co' ",
    "code" : 16722,
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need an [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to compare two fields in MongoDB. Since you have an array (`collection`) and you want to check if there's any element where fields match you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) operators like below:

```
db.col.find({
    $expr: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: "$collections",
                in: {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.collection_code", "$attributes.collection_code" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

There is also more succinct way by using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) operator

```
db.col.find({
    $expr: {
        $in: [ "$attributes.collection_code", "$collections.collection_code" ]
    }
})
```

it works because `collections.collection_code` represents an array of strings in this case.

EDIT:
As a workaround for 3.0 version you can use `$anyElementTrue` with [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $redact: {
        $cond: {
        if: {$anyElementTrue: { $map: { input: "$collections", as: "c", in: { $eq: [ "$$c.collection_code", "$attributes.collection_code" ]  }  }}},
        then: "$$KEEP",
        else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
    }
])
```

Comment: Do we need to put any bracket before $expr as I am getting an error - `Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $expr`

Comment: What MongoDB version you have ?

Comment: Current version is  3.0.11

Comment: 3.0 is unsupported. 3.2 is unsupported. 3.4 is soon to be unsupported. You should really look at upgrading your cluster.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra $expr was introduced in 3.6 but I've just modified my answer and this workaround should be fine for you

Comment: Now the error is `exception: invalid operator '$in' code 15999` .  I am using free version of NoSQLBooster.

Comment: `$in` was intrduced in 3.4 but you can use this syntax with $map, modified my answer

Comment: Now there is no error but I was expecting some records. Also modified this line by adding 'as' -- `input: "$collections", as: "collection", in: { $eq: [ "$this.collection_code", "$attributes.collection_code" ]  } `

Comment: You should have `in: { $eq: [ "$$collection.collection_code", "$attributes.collection_code" ] }` if you can't use `$$this`

Comment: No error and it returns zero records which seems odd. I know there are atleast couple of documents where the codes are same but not sure why it returns zero.

Comment: @RobertSeaman I can upgrade but in that case I need to upgrade the current node code too.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Now getting `exception: input to $map must be an Array not Object`

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra so in your example `collections` is an array and it works, how about your real database ? Is it an array or something different ?

Comment: sorry for replying late. It's same in the real database too. While running the query I am getting a red mark here - `$eq: [` . Might be sql syntax error?

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra ah that's my fault, a comma was missing there, you can check it out here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RAa7rtEEpS5

Comment: Quite close now. Getting this error - `"exception: input to $map must be an Array not Object",` I think this is because we have the documents inside an array in Mongo Playground for eg [{},{},{}] but when we use query to the db then there is no array.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra could you paste the document that causes an exception since the query works fine for the one you posted in your question ?

Comment: @mickl It's not the document which is causing the issue. I think it's the array which is not present while querying the db for multiple documents.

Comment: So the only thing you can do is to filter out those documents without array before applying this code